# C++: Redefine one or the other operation in the child class

Tags: c++

In the following code:

```
class GraphicalCardDeck : public CardDeck, public GraphicalObject {
public:
    virtual void draw () {
        return CardDeck::draw();
    }
    virtual void paint () {
        GraphicalObject::draw();
    }
}

GraphicalCardDeck gcd;
gcd->draw();          // selects CardDeck draw
gcd->paint();         // selects GraphicalObject draw
```

When in the class `CardDeck` there is a function named `draw`, and in the class `GraphicalObject` there is a function named `draw`.

The book mentions a problem when we do:

```
GraphicalObject* g = new GraphicalCardDeck();
g->draw(); // opps, doing wrong method!
```

Why will it call the wrong method? It will not call the function `draw` in the class `CardDeck` as we define?

Thank you.

Comment: You tagged this as "Java" and mention "Java" in your title, but the code seems to be C++. What are you **actually** asking about?

Comment: Are you sure this is Java? I don't know of a `->` operator in Java ...

Comment: `GraphicalObject* g = new GraphicalCardDeck();` I'm not sure if this line works!!

Comment: Ye, I know.. but this is what writen in the book. I confuse too..

Comment: @Mayank : Yes, of course that works, as `GraphicalCardDeck` inherits publicly from `GraphicalObject`.

Comment: @ildjarn: Thanks a lot. I did not know this. I thought we need a cast

Comment: @Mayank : Sometimes, not always, and not in this particular case; C++ allows implicit initialization/assignment of *covariant* pointer types.

Comment: @Tom - can you clarify whether `GraphicalObject::draw()` is declared with the keyword `virtual` or not?

Comment: I am curious to know what book you are learning from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it will call the function `draw` in the `CardDeck` as we defined. But that might be surprising to someone not familiar with the internals of our class:

```
GraphicalObject* g = new GraphicalCardDeck();
g->draw(); // opps, doing wrong method!
```

Someone that wrote this might expect that `GraphicalObject::draw()` is called (or at least an overwritten version of that function that provides the same functionality). Since our overwritten function provides completely different functionality (that required by `CardDeck`), from the perspective of the one writing the above code the "wrong" function is called (aka. not the one he intended to call).

So it works like you expected, but when just looking at the interface and without knowledge of the internal implementation one might expect different behavior.

Comment: It will invoke `GraphicalCardDeck::draw()` (and in turn, `CardDeck::draw()`) **only if** `GraphicalObject::draw()` is declared `virtual`.